# FetchedResultsController update after changing of dependent entity

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

[image: Database scheme]

Assume I have following class model.
I have `UITableView` which displays data from `Days` table in following way:

```
Monday 02.03
5 lessons


Wednesday 04.03
3 lessons
```

The task is straightforward. I can create a FetchedResultsController like this and use it as data source for TableView:

```
[Days MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"day" ascending:YES withPredicate:filter groupBy:nil delegate:self]
```

later:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...
   cell.lessonsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d lessons", [day.dayToLesson count]];
```

Using this approach I can get desired output. Additionally, I'd like to refresh TableView if number of lessons changed (someone inserted in Lessons table). How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a delegate on the `NSFetchedResultsController`. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW26) which give details on how to set up the delegate methods and [respond to changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW28) in the table.

Comment: Please, read initial post carefully! I know, how FRC delegate works. I need to update TableView after `Lessons` update (FRC is based on `Days` entity!)

Comment: If you add a `Lessons` to the `Days` object it will be marked as changed and notify the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate. You probably shouldn't use the pluralized form for the `Days` and `Lessons` either, it doesn't make much sense. `Day` should have a `lessons` relationship, and `Lesson` should have a `day` relationship.

Comment: I don't have notifications from FRC on `Days` entity if I update `Lessons` entity. Can you post code, please?

Comment: If you insert (or delete) a `Lessons` into a `Days` you'll get a delegate method call (that's what your original question asked - "someone inserted in Lessons table"). If you update a `Lessons` you won't get that. You'll need to add another `NSFetchedResultsController` on the `Lessons` for the current `Days` if you want to pick that up.